# maintain multiple socket connections while putting the recv through a single handler in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, host

I have a function that returns a host for a specific site. and using these two functions

```
def connect(self, rooms):
    print('')
    i = [x for x in rooms]
    for x in i:
        self.room_connect(x)
    running = True            
    while running:
        self.event_data()`

def room_connect(self, rooms):
    host = getServer(rooms)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, 443)) 
    sock.send(self.room_auth(rooms).encode())
    self.sockets = sock
    print(self.sockets)
    print('connected to '+ rooms)
    self.postbyte = True
```

i am able to connect to a different socket for each host. the problem is, i need it to maintain a connection with each socket it connects to. in the end, only the last socket that is created in the for loop is maintained. the socket recv data from that socket is passed in to a handler to parse the info. basically what i am asking is how to keep a connection from each of the sockets created in the for loop going while passing its recv info in to the handler. the handler is the event_data() and in the event_data function the data to parse is defined by data = self.sockets.recv(1024). the problem is that the only the last socket from the for loop is left over to be handled.

Comment: It would help if you'd show the rest of the class definition, too.  Hard to tell exactly what your different variables are doing.  self.sockets is probably the most interesting, but all of it (that is referenced from this code) would be good.

Comment: self.sockets = None in the __init__ under the class

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a dictionary.  Then you can look it up easily in the future by whatever you want.

Comment: what i need is for it to stay connected to every socket it creates

Comment: @user2602977 Once you put it in a dictionary, your socket object will stick around, so your connection will stay open -- and you'll actually be able to reference it, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with xaxxon's approach. Put the connections (socket fds) in a queue (based on the value of "host" as the key). But, if you want event_data to recv data from various sockets, then you would likely need additional mechanisms since recv() call is blocking and if you have multiple hosts, this might be a problem. You would probably need to use either select() or multi-threading or both.

Comment: i have seen select used like this before although i have no idea how to use it myself. i have it connecting and maintaining the connections now by putting the sockets in a dict `self.socks = list(self.sockets.values())`, although like you said the recv is only getting the info from the latest connection made (the last socket in the list)

Comment: With select(), we can pass multiple file descriptors (fds) and when we get any events on them, select() call returns and it sets the fd that has the event; file descriptors are the returned values of the socket() call and would be the sock variable in your code. Thus, upon return, we can check what fd was set and then issue recv() call on that (assuming we are checking read events). This way, with select, we have only one blocking call, instead of doing a blocking recv() call for each fds.  YOu might find this helpful: http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Comment: @user2602977 you need to actually post ALL the relevant code.  If you are going to ask additional questions based on changes, you need to update your question with the new code.